# How should you pass canvas context to methods in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First time working with canvas in react. I am wondering what the best way to provide methods with the canvas context is (like paint below). Should I use Refs? State? Or is there another way. Thanks

Here is what I have for using refs so far:

```
class Canvas  extends React.Component{
  canvasRef = React.createRef();
  contextRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.contextRef.current = context;
  }

  paint = (e) => {
    this.contextRef.current.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    this.contextRef.current.stroke();
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      canvas id = "canvas"
      ref = {
        this.canvasRef
      }
      onMouseMove = {
        this.paint
      }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refs are correct for getting the canvas, but I'd suggest getting the 2D context each time you need it ([`getContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) just returns the same context as the previous time).

You have a few other minor issues with that code, here's an example putting the context in an instance property, and fixing various issues called out inline.

```
class Canvas extends React.Component { // *** Note: You need to extend `React.Component`
    canvasRef = React.createRef(); // *** Note: You shouldn't have `this.` here
  
    paint = (e) => {
        // ** Get the canvas
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
        if (!canvas) {
            return; // This probably won't happen
        }
        // Get the context
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // Get the point to draw at, allowing for the possibility
        // that the canvas isn't at the top of the doc
        const { left, top } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - left;
        const y = e.clientY - top;
        context.lineTo(x, y);
        context.stroke();
    }; // *** Added missing ; here
  
    render() {
        return <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} onMouseMove={this.paint} />;
    }
}
```

*(I removed the `id` on the canvas, since your component might get used in more than one place.)*

In a comment you mentioned issues with state changes causing trouble (I saw that as well when trying to get and keep the context rather than getting it each time), so I've added state both to a parent container element and also to the `Canvas` element in the following example to check that it continues to work, which it does:

```js
const { useState } = React;

class Canvas extends React.Component { // *** Note: You need to extend `React.Component`
    canvasRef = React.createRef(); // *** Note: You shouldn't have `this.` here
  
    state = {
        ticker: 0,
    };
    
    paint = (e) => {
        // ** Get the canvas
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
        if (!canvas) {
            return; // This probably won't happen
        }
        // Get the context
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // Get the point to draw at, allowing for the possibility
        // that the canvas isn't at the top of the doc
        const { left, top } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = e.clientX - left;
        const y = e.clientY - top;
        context.lineTo(x, y);
        context.stroke();
    }; // *** Added missing ; here
  
    increment = () => {
        this.setState(( { ticker }) => ({ ticker: ticker + 1 }));
    };
    
    render() {
        const { ticker } = this.state;
        return <div>
            <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} onMouseMove={this.paint} />
            <div onClick={this.increment}>Canvas ticker: {ticker}</div>
        </div>;
    }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ticker: 0,
    };
    
    increment = () => {
        this.setState(({ ticker }) => ({ ticker: ticker + 1 }));
    };
    
    render() {
        const { ticker } = this.state;
        return <div>
            <div onClick={this.increment}>Parent ticker: {ticker}</div>
            <Canvas />
        </div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, I will have a go. Thanks T.J, sorry for the simple issues with the code.

Comment: @HarryS - No worries! We were all new at this once. :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I'm having some issues, the code works fine however if I want to setState and so re-render the component it stops working. How do I retain this instance property after a re-render? Thanks

Comment: @HarryS - No worries at all. Yeah, I see issues retaining the 2D context object too. I think you're best off just getting it as you need it, the docs say you get the same one back anyway. I've updated the answer, and added state in two places in the runnable example to make sure it works correctly across state changes.

Comment: That works well, thanks for your help T.J!